# namespaced jquery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, namespaces

what is the correct syntax to create a namespace within jquery, so as to allow the passing of the matched set to nested methods?

this is what I have:

```
(function($) {
    var nameSpace = {
        module: function(x){

        }
    }
})(jQuery)
```

but calling `$('.selector').nameSpace.module()` returns

```
Cannot call method 'module' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work as you have not added anything to `jQuery.fn`, which is where all plugins get added. You will likely run into issues even if you did this though as jQuery does some fancy things with how `this` is bound.

If you wish to have multiple methods on a single plugin i would suggest reading through the [jQuery documentation on namespacing plugins](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Namespacing)

Hope that helps